# Change the height of the panel of the split container at runtime

Tags: vb.net, winforms, splitcontainer

I have a splitcontainer and I would change the height of the panel1 at runtime. I use this code

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SplitContainer1.Panel1.Height = 2
    End Sub
```

It's possible ? Does anybody have any suggestion?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: 2 is a very small number.  Are you sure you just don't want to call `splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = true;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the property `SplitContainer.SplitterDistance`.  From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.splitterdistance.aspx):

> Gets or sets the location of the splitter, in pixels, from the left or top edge of the SplitContainer.

Answer (score 2):

Per my comment, you should consider just calling

```
splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = true;
```

since the height of 2 is a very small number.  Not much use to the user.

Otherwise, you would have to set the following two properties:

```
splitContainer1.Panel1MinSize = 2;
splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 2;
```